# Error while running make command [Packet Generator in DPDK]

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to install packet generator in my system. I have downloaded packet generator from DPDK.org. I follow the instructions mentioned in the following [link](http://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

When I run the make command I get the below error:

```
  /root/DPDK/pktgen-dpdk/app/pktgen-latency.c:17:25: fatal error: rte_bus_pci.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  /root/DPDK/dpdk-stable-17.08.1//mk/internal/rte.compile-pre.mk:138: 
  recipe for target 'pktgen-latency.o' failed
  make[2]: *** [pktgen-latency.o] Error 1
  /root/DPDK/dpdk-stable-17.08.1//mk/rte.extapp.mk:47: recipe for 
  target 'pktgen' failed
  make[1]: *** [pktgen] Error 2
  /root/DPDK/dpdk-stable-17.08.1//mk/rte.extsubdir.mk:48: recipe for 
  target 'app' failed
  make: *** [app] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading the version of DPDK solves this issue. I used a version of 17.08 and later on upgraded it to 17.11

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the RTE_TARGET is set incorrectly or DPDK is not compiled. First we set:

```
export RTE_SDK=<DPDKInstallDir>
export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc
```

Then we compile DPDK and then Pktgen.

Comment: I did that as mentioned in the documentation. But I just tried changed the version of DPDK from 17.08 to 17.11 and it worked.